# Slurm Can't find plugin for select/linear

Tags: archlinux, slurm

I have been following [this guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Slurm) to install Slurm on my node. I tried merely copying the slurmd example to slurm.conf and running `sudo start slurmd`, as per the guide, that generated this error output in journalctl:

```
Dec 29 19:16:22 Node_2 slurmd[27681]: error: plugin_load_from_file: dlopen(/usr/lib/slurm/select_linear.so): /usr/lib/slurm/select_linear.so: undefined symbol: slurm_job_preempt_mode
Dec 29 19:16:22 Node_2 slurmd[27681]: error: Couldn't load specified plugin name for select/linear: Dlopen of plugin file failed
Dec 29 19:16:22 Node_2 systemd[1]: slurmd.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Dec 29 19:16:22 Node_2 slurmd[27681]: fatal: Can't find plugin for select/linear
Dec 29 19:16:22 Node_2 systemd[1]: slurmd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 29 19:16:22 Node_2 systemd[1]: Failed to start Slurm node daemon.
```

However, I do have this plugin, I can see it:

```
sudo ls /usr/lib/slurm/select_linear.so
/usr/lib/slurm/select_linear.so
```

I also tried, `sudo slurmd -cDvvvvv` and got the following output.

```
slurmd: error: plugin_load_from_file: dlopen(/usr/lib/slurm/select_linear.so): /usr/lib/slurm/select_linear.so: undefined symbol: slurm_job_preempt_mode
slurmd: error: Couldn't load specified plugin name for select/linear: Dlopen of plugin file failed
slurmd: fatal: Can't find plugin for select/linear
```

I also tried `sudo slurmctld -cDvvvvv` and got this:

```
slurmctld: debug:  Log file re-opened
slurmctld: debug:  creating clustername file: /var/spool/slurm/ctld/clustername
slurmctld: Stack size set to 8388608
slurmctld: slurmctld version 17.11.0 started on cluster linux
slurmctld: debug3: Trying to load plugin /usr/lib/slurm/crypto_munge.so
slurmctld: Munge cryptographic signature plugin loaded
slurmctld: debug3: Success.
slurmctld: debug3: Trying to load plugin /usr/lib/slurm/select_linear.so
slurmctld: debug3: Success.
slurmctld: debug3: Trying to load plugin /usr/lib/slurm/preempt_none.so
slurmctld: preempt/none loaded
slurmctld: debug3: Success.
slurmctld: debug3: Trying to load plugin /usr/lib/slurm/checkpoint_none.so
slurmctld: debug3: Success.
slurmctld: debug:  Checkpoint plugin loaded: checkpoint/none
slurmctld: debug3: Trying to load plugin /usr/lib/slurm/acct_gather_energy_none.so
slurmctld: debug:  AcctGatherEnergy NONE plugin loaded
slurmctld: debug3: Success.
slurmctld: debug3: Trying to load plugin /usr/lib/slurm/acct_gather_profile_none.so
slurmctld: debug:  AcctGatherProfile NONE plugin loaded
slurmctld: debug3: Success.
slurmctld: debug3: Trying to load plugin /usr/lib/slurm/acct_gather_interconnect_none.so
slurmctld: debug:  AcctGatherInterconnect NONE plugin loaded
slurmctld: debug3: Success.
slurmctld: debug3: Trying to load plugin /usr/lib/slurm/acct_gather_filesystem_none.so
slurmctld: debug:  AcctGatherFilesystem NONE plugin loaded
slurmctld: debug3: Success.
slurmctld: debug2: No acct_gather.conf file (/etc/slurm-llnl/acct_gather.conf)
slurmctld: debug3: Trying to load plugin /usr/lib/slurm/jobacct_gather_none.so
slurmctld: debug:  Job accounting gather NOT_INVOKED plugin loaded
slurmctld: debug3: Success.
slurmctld: debug3: Trying to load plugin /usr/lib/slurm/ext_sensors_none.so
slurmctld: ExtSensors NONE plugin loaded
slurmctld: debug3: Success.
slurmctld: debug3: Trying to load plugin /usr/lib/slurm/switch_none.so
slurmctld: debug:  switch NONE plugin loaded
slurmctld: debug3: Success.
slurmctld: debug:  power_save module disabled, SuspendTime < 0
slurmctld: error: this host (Node_2/Node_2) not a valid controller (linux0 or (null))
```

Any idea what I need to do for it to see this plugin?

Comment: Did you check the plug-in was built with the same version of the running SLURM ?

Comment: it is an arch linux pacman package, no reason why it shouldn't be unless you know specifically what I am suppose to be looking for, because I do not, https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/slurm-llnl/

Comment: Is the unresolved symbol defined in an other plugin ? If yes, then try loading this plugin first. In any cases, that looks like a bug to me.

Answer (score 0):

To me, that looks like a bug in SLURM.

My guess is that the `select/linear` plugin only makes sense when used by `slurmctld` and not when used by `slurmd`.
The `slurm_job_preempt_mode` symbol is indeed defined in `slurmctld` but not in `slurmd`.

FWIW, a slightly older version with the same "missing" symbol in `slurmd` works just fine on RHEL7, so i guess the behavior depends on the linker (configuration) of the OS.

My best bet is you report this issue directly to the SLURM folks.

Comment: fwiw, i built on an up-to-date `arch linux` the latest `17.11.2-1` and the behavior is the same :-(

Comment: That was you?! Thanks for the try, was hoping that was going to work out.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with another plugin (lua).
My solution was to mention it at rpmbuild:

```
rpmbuild --with lua -ta slurm-16.05.7.tar.bz2
```

maybe this will help you too, I would try something like

```
rpmbuild --with linear -ta slurm-16.05.7.tar.bz2
```